# How to run Django app from lan using development server

Tags: django

I know that this question has been already asked but the answers didn't help me.
I ran the command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and
now the site is accessible from the computer using `localhost:8000` but how can i run it on other devices connected to the local wifi network ?

Comment: It depends on where you run it (your computer OS). If you have mac or hack: http://superuser.com/questions/417910/osx-lion-open-a-local-port-so-people-on-my-network-can-access-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network question: `localhost` is an alias for your local IP 127.0.0.1.

You can start Django server on an another address as following:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.100.1:8080
```

Where `192.168.100.1` is your IP on local network. See [official commands' docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) for more details.